# Django: correct way to specify model (list of tuples)

Tags: python, django, database-design

I'm not happy with my current model and wanted to ask if there is a better/preferred way to achieve the same result.

*What do I want?*

- An object A that contains a number of lists. Each list contains tuples, the first entry being a date object, the second one is either a float or an integer.
- If I delete A, B should also be deleted. If I delete B I want to just have an empty list.

*How I tried to accomplish it:*

```
class TimeValueIntSequence(models.Model):
    pass

class TimeValueFloatSequence(models.Model):
    pass

class TimeValueInt(models.Model):
    time = models.DateField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    sequence = models.ForeignKey(TimeValueIntSequence, models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)

class TimeValueFloat(models.Model):
    time = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    sequence = models.ForeignKey(TimeValueFloatSequence, models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)

class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.OneToOneField(TimeValueIntSequence, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='field1')
    field2 = models.OneToOneField(TimeValueIntSequence, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='field2')
    field3 = models.OneToOneField(TimeValueFloatSequence, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='field3')
```

*What is wrong?*

- Approach seems inefficient.
- If I delete an object of type A the sequences do not get deleted.

Do you have any feedback?
Thank you!

Comment: seems like JSON is the answer. Not a big fan because of the added overhead so let me know if you have something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better solution so I ended up using JSON. If you have the same problem make sure to use DjangoJSONEncoder to deal with the date-time objects.

Remark: Would be nice if Django could abstract that and enable you to story arbitrary datatypes as long as they are serializable. If you know how, let me know.